# Update sticky toastr notification and programmatically close

Tags: jquery, toastr

I want to have an ongoing notification of sorts.  I'm querying a bunch of records and I'd like it to be fairly verbose.  What I want is a toastr notification that pops up and says "Retrieving details for  ( of )"

Then when it's done retrieving them all, I'd like the notification to fade out.

How hard would this be?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm .. might already be possible without code changes. Maybe. You could extend the timeout as the toast continues, and update the contents of the toast. I cant try this right now, but give it a shot. If not, I'll circle back on this next week.

Comment: hey John nice plugin! I'm having a semi-related issue to this question. I have a recursive rest process being performed that requires sequential notifications. The problem is that every time I fetch new data it runs a brand new instance of toastr.info(message); which builds a new container instead of placing the new messages inside of the original container--this causes funky stacking. How have you guys handled calling toastr recursively so far if at all?